# need guidance with retrieving data from span id

Tags: python

hoping for a little help, i need to scrap the the id and temperature. I have tried a couple things but i cannot get it right can someone help.i am using BeautifulSoup to get the information then print it

```
<span id="root.content.BoundLabel12.text">21.1 ºC</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
... 
... soup = BeautifulSoup(
...     '<span id="root.content.BoundLabel12.text">21.1 ºC</span>'
... )
>>> span_id = soup.span['id']
>>> span_id
'root.content.BoundLabel12.text'
>>> temperature = soup.span.text
>>> temperature
'21.1 ºC'
```